# Can EF 6 get DbSet from table/view without definition of a class?

Tags: entity-framework

Table/View should have all column infos, I don't get why I have to define a class if I just want to return all columns, seems it is pretty trouble you have to modify the class everytime you add/remove a column from the table/view?

Comment: That is exactly what [strongly-typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) means.  Otherwise how would any query statement work where you want to limit columns with select, or use where statements?

Comment: but you can get column data type, length from table/view info from the db, right?

Comment: Yes, but not making a strongly-type object for Entity-Framework, pretty much means... don't use entity-framework.